# Is there any way how to fix my coding for fare guide drop-down?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating this page to make people know faster what price of that fare from origin to destination. It's about train fare guide, with number of stations is 20 which it shows the price quickly.

But there's a problem, some options are not showing the prices and some are showing incorrectly and I need to match the fare in the picture.

Is there any way how to fix this?

My code should match with here

[image]

This is my code:

Some results are very accurate, some of them are wrong, and some of them are not showing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```js
function DisplayPrice(price) {
  var val1 = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.form1.price.length; i++) {
    if (document.form1.price[i].checked == true) {
      val1 = document.form1.price[i].value;
    }
  }
  var val2 = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.form2.price2.length; i++) {
    if (document.form2.price2[i].checked == true) {
      val2 = document.form2.price2[i].value;
    }
  }
  if (val2 == 0) {
    val1 = 0;
  }
  if (val1 == 0) {
    val2 = 0;
  }
  var sum = parseInt(val1) - parseInt(val2);
  var a = Math.abs(sum);
  if (a == 0) {
    document.getElementById('valueTotal').value = "P0.00";
  } else if ((a <= 1) || (a == 2) || (a == 3) || (a == 4) || (a == 5) || (a == 6)) {
    document.getElementById('valueTotal').value = "P15.00";
  } else if ((a == 7) || (a == 8) || (a == 9) || (a == 10) || (a == 11) || (a == 12)) {
    document.getElementById('valueTotal').value = "P20.00";
  } else if ((a == 13) || (a == 14) || (a == 15) || (a == 16) || (a == 17) || (a == 18) || (a == 19) || (a == 20)) {
    document.getElementById('valueTotal').value = "P30.00";
  }
  //val1
  if (val1 == 1) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Roosevelt";
  } else if (val1 == 2) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Balintawak";
  } else if (val1 == 3) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Monumento";
  } else if (val1 == 4) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "5th Avenue";
  } else if (val1 == 5) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "R. Papa";
  } else if (val1 == 6) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Abad Santos";
  } else if (val1 == 7) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Blumentritt";
  } else if (val1 == 8) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Tayuman";
  } else if (val1 == 9) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Bambang";
  } else if (val1 == 10) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Doroteo Jose";
  } else if (val1 == 11) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Carriedo";
  } else if (val1 == 12) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Central Terminal";
  } else if (val1 == 13) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "United Nations";
  } else if (val1 == 14) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Pedro Gil";
  } else if (val1 == 15) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Quirino";
  } else if (val1 == 16) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Vito Cruz";
  } else if (val1 == 17) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Gil Puyat";
  } else if (val1 == 18) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Ayala";
  } else if (val1 == 19) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "EDSA";
  } else if (val1 == 20) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Baclaran";
  }
  //val2
  if (val2 != 0) {
    document.getElementById('valueName1').value = "to";
  }
  if (val2 == 1) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Roosevelt";
  } else if (val2 == 2) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Balintawak";
  } else if (val2 == 3) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Monumento";
  } else if (val2 == 4) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "5th Avenue";
  } else if (val2 == 5) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "R. Papa";
  } else if (val2 == 6) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Abad Santos";
  } else if (val2 == 7) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Blumentritt";
  } else if (val2 == 8) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Tayuman";
  } else if (val2 == 9) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Bambang";
  } else if (val2 == 10) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Doroteo Jose";
  } else if (val2 == 11) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Carriedo";
  } else if (val2 == 12) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Central Terminal";
  } else if (val2 == 13) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "United Nations";
  } else if (val2 == 14) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Pedro Gil";
  } else if (val2 == 15) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Quirino";
  } else if (val2 == 16) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Vito Cruz";
  } else if (val2 == 17) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Gil Puyat";
  } else if (val2 == 18) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Ayala";
  } else if (val2 == 19) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "EDSA";
  } else if (val2 == 20) {
    document.getElementById('valueName').value = "Baclaran";
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  if (x == 'Baclaran') {
    var station1 = 1;
  } else if (x == 'EDSA') {
    var station1 = 2;
  } else if (x == 'Libertad') {
    var station1 = 3;
  } else if (x == 'Gil Puyat') {
    var station1 = 4;
  } else if (x == 'Vito Cruz') {
    var station1 = 5;
  } else if (x == 'Quirino') {
    var station1 = 6;
  } else if (x == 'Pedro Gil') {
    var station1 = 7;
  } else if (x == 'United Nations') {
    var station1 = 8;
  } else if (x == 'Central Terminal') {
    var station1 = 9;
  } else if (x == 'Carriedo') {
    var station1 = 10;
  } else if (x == 'Doroteo Jose') {
    var station1 = 11;
  } else if (x == 'Bambang') {
    var station1 = 12;
  } else if (x == 'Tayuman') {
    var station1 = 13;
  } else if (x == 'Blumentritt') {
    var station1 = 14;
  } else if (x == 'Abad Santos') {
    var station1 = 15;
  } else if (x == 'R. Papa') {
    var station1 = 16;
  } else if (x == '5th Avenue') {
    var station1 = 17;
  } else if (x == 'Monumento') {
    var station1 = 18;
  } else if (x == 'Balintawak') {
    var station1 = 19;
  } else if (x == 'Roosevelt') {
    var station1 = 20;
  }
  var y = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
  if (y == 'Baclaran') {
    var station2 = 1;
  } else if (y == 'EDSA') {
    var station2 = 2;
  } else if (y == 'Libertad') {
    var station2 = 3;
  } else if (y == 'Gil Puyat') {
    var station2 = 4;
  } else if (y == 'Vito Cruz') {
    var station2 = 5;
  } else if (y == 'Quirino') {
    var station2 = 6;
  } else if (y == 'Pedro Gil') {
    var station2 = 7;
  } else if (y == 'United Nations') {
    var station2 = 8;
  } else if (y == 'Central Terminal') {
    var station2 = 9;
  } else if (y == 'Carriedo') {
    var station2 = 10;
  } else if (y == 'Doroteo Jose') {
    var station2 = 11;
  } else if (y == 'Bambang') {
    var station2 = 12;
  } else if (y == 'Tayuman') {
    var station2 = 13;
  } else if (x == 'Blumentritt') {
    var station2 = 14;
  } else if (x == 'Abad Santos') {
    var station2 = 15;
  } else if (x == 'R. Papa') {
    var station2 = 16;
  } else if (x == '5th Avenue') {
    var station2 = 17;
  } else if (x == 'Monumento') {
    var station2 = 18;
  } else if (x == 'Balintawak') {
    var station2 = 19;
  } else if (x == 'Roosevelt') {
    var station2 = 20;
  }
  if (station2 != "") {
    document.getElementById('mep').innerHTML = "to";
  }
  if (station1 == '') {
    station2 = 0;
  }
  if (station2 == '') {
    station1 = 0;
  }
  var sum = station1 - station2;
  var c = Math.abs(sum);
  if (c == 0) {
    document.getElementById('tot').innerHTML = "P0.00";
  } else if ((c == 1) || (c == 2) || (c == 3) || (c == 4) || (c == 5) || (c == 6)) {
    document.getElementById('tot').innerHTML = "P15.00";
  } else if ((c == 7) || (c == 8) || (c == 9) || (c == 10) || (c == 11) || (c == 12)) {
    document.getElementById('tot').innerHTML = "P20.00";
  } else if ((c == 13) || (c == 14) || (c == 15) || (c == 16) || (c == 17) || (c == 18) || (c == 19) || (c == 20)) {
    document.getElementById('tot').innerHTML = "P30.00";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; width: 0px; height: 0px;">
  </div>
</div>
<h1>LRT-1 FAREGUIDE</h1>SINGLE JOURNEY TICKET
<br>
<br class="punta">ORIGIN
<pbr>
  <div class="select1">
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="" selected> </option>
      <option value="Baclaran">Baclaran</option>
      <option value="EDSA">EDSA</option>
      <option value="Libertad">Libertad</option>
      <option value="Gil Puyat">Gil Puyat</option>
      <option value="Vito Cruz">Vito Cruz</option>
      <option value="Quirino">Quirino</option>
      <option value="Pedro Gil">Pedro Gil</option>
      <option value="United Nations">United Nations</option>
      <option value="Central Terminal">Central Terminal</option>
      <option value="Carriedo">Carriedo</option>
      <option value="Doroteo Jose">Doroteo Jose</option>
      <option value="Bambang">Bambang</option>
      <option value="Tayuman">Tayuman</option>
      <option value="Blumentritt">Blumentritt</option>
      <option value="Abad Santos">Abad Santos</option>
      <option value="R. Papa">R. Papa</option>
      <option value="5th Avenue">5th Avenue</option>
      <option value="Monumento">Monumento</option>
      <option value="Balintawak">Balintawak</option>
      <option value="Roosevelt">Roosevelt</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br class="punta">DESTINATION</br>
  <div class="select2">
    <select id="mySelect2" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="" selected> </option>
      <option value="Baclaran">Baclaran</option>
      <option value="EDSA">EDSA</option>
      <option value="Libertad">Libertad</option>
      <option value="Gil Puyat">Gil Puyat</option>
      <option value="Vito Cruz">Vito Cruz</option>
      <option value="Quirino">Quirino</option>
      <option value="Pedro Gil">Pedro Gil</option>
      <option value="United Nations">United Nations</option>
      <option value="Central Terminal">Central Terminal</option>
      <option value="Carriedo">Carriedo</option>
      <option value="Doroteo Jose">Doroteo Jose</option>
      <option value="Bambang">Bambang</option>
      <option value="Tayuman">Tayuman</option>
      <option value="Blumentritt">Blumentritt</option>
      <option value="Abad Santos">Abad Santos</option>
      <option value="R. Papa">R. Papa</option>
      <option value="5th Avenue">5th Avenue</option>
      <option value="Monumento">Monumento</option>
      <option value="Balintawak">Balintawak</option>
      <option value="Roosevelt">Roosevelt</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="loc">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="mep"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <p id="tot"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor like I just did for you

Comment: Note the minimal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove half your code since it is not relevant to the HTML

Then you need to be more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) Your code can be reduced to a 10th and then be much more debuggable

Here is a simpler version using the selectedIndex of the selects

Please add the relevant prices in the arrays that are still empty

```js
const fares = {
  "Baclaran":        [ 0, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
  "EDSA":            [15,  0, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
  "Libertad":        [],
  "Gil Puyat":       [],
  "Vito Cruz":       [],
  "Quirino":         [],
  "Pedro Gil":       [],
  "United Nations":  [],
  "Central Terminal":[],
  "Carriedo":        [],
  "Doroteo Jose":    [],
  "Bambang":         [],
  "Tayuman":         [],
  "Blumentritt":     [],
  "Abad Santos":     [],
  "R. Papa":         [],
  "5th Avenue":      [],
  "Yamaha Monumento":[],
  "Balintawak":      [],
  "Roosevelt":       [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 15, 15,  0]
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when page has loaded
  const from = document.getElementById("origin");
  const to = document.getElementById("destination");
  const output = document.getElementById("output");
  const price = document.getElementById("price");
  const stations = Object
    .keys(fares)
    .map(station => `<option value="${station}">${station}</option>`).join("");
  from.innerHTML += stations;
  to.innerHTML += stations;
  const getFare = (fromStation, toIdx) => `P${fares[fromStation][toIdx].toFixed(2)}`; // using Template Literals


  const displayPrice = (e) => {
    output.textContent = "" // empty
    let fromVal = from.value;
    let toVal = to.value;
    if (fromVal === "" || toVal === "") return // stop processing if one is empty
    let fromIdx = from.selectedIndex-1; // arrays start at 0
    let toIdx = to.selectedIndex-1;
    let a = Math.abs(fromIdx - toIdx);
    output.textContent = `${fromVal} to ${toVal}`
    price.textContent = getFare(fromVal, toIdx);
  };
  from.addEventListener("change", displayPrice);
  to.addEventListener("change", displayPrice);
});
```

```html
<br class="punta">ORIGIN
<div class="select1">
  <select id="origin">
    <option value="" selected>Origin</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br class="punta">DESTINATION</br>
<div class="select2">
  <select id="destination">
    <option value="">Destination</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="loc">
  <p id="output"></p>
  <p id="price"></p>
</div>
```